# Azure WebApp - Multiple Custom Domains in single request

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-cli

I'm trying to bulk upload custom domains to Azure WebApps (specifically the deployment slots). I currently loop through with Azure CLI but it adds 15-20 minutes to CICD process.

I've also tried with ARM Templates but it reports a "conflict" during bulk upload. It requires a condition or dependency on the previous hostname which means it's still configuring the domains one by one.

Does anyone know of a way to bulk configure?

**Powershell and Azure CLI**

```
#Set Host Names and SSL
  $WebApp_HostNames = Import-Csv "$(ConfigFiles_Path)\$WebApp-Hostnames.csv"
  if ($null -ne $WebApp_HostNames) {
    foreach ($HostName in $WebApp_HostNames) {
      az webapp config hostname add --hostname $HostName.Name --resource-group "$(ResourceGroup)" --webapp-name "$WebApp" --slot "$WebApp$(WebApp_Slot_Suffix)"
      az webapp config ssl bind --certificate-thumbprint $HostName.Thumbprint --ssl-type SNI --resource-group "$(ResourceGroup)" --name "$WebApp"  --slot "$WebApp$(WebApp_Slot_Suffix)"
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**: Got it! Will write out the process and provide the answer here for future reference

Comment: We have the same experience. Looking forward your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I've included the entire Powershell script here including getting your auth token and pushing the json config. There's nothing else you'll need to bulk upload.

Hope this helps

```
# Get auth token from existing Context
$currentAzureContext = Get-AzContext
$azProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azProfile)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.Tenant.TenantId)

# Authorisation Header
$authHeader = @{
 'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
 'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + ($token.AccessToken)
}

# Request URL
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{WebAppName}/slots/{WebAppSlotName}?api-version=2018-11-01"

# JSON body
$body = '
{
    "id":"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{WebAppName}/slots/{WebAppSlotName}",
    "kind":"app",
    "location":"Australia East",
    "name":"{WebAppName} or {WebAppSlotName}",
    "type":"Microsoft.Web/sites/slots", or "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "properties":{
        "hostNameSslStates":[
            {
                "name":"sub1.domain.com",
                "sslState":"SniEnabled",
                "thumbprint":"IUAHSIUHASD78ASDIUABFKASF79ASUASD8ASFHOANKSL",
                "toUpdate":true,
                "hostType":"Standard"
            
            },
            {
                "name":"sub2.domain.com",
                "sslState":"SniEnabled",
                "thumbprint":"FHISGF8A7SFG9SUGBSA7G9ASHIAOSHDF08ASHDF08AS",
                "toUpdate":true,
                "hostType":"Standard"
            
            }
        ],
        "hostNames":[
            "sub1.domain.com",
            "sub2.domain.com",
            "{Default WebApp Domain}"
        ]
    }
}
'

# Push to Azure
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Body $body -Method PUT -Headers $authHeader
```

**Method**

In the end I just pressed F12 to capture the traffic in the Networking tab in browser developer tools.

When clicking "Add Binding" in portal there's one `PUT` request which has the payload required to replicate. I found that the request contains ALL of the Custom Domains and SSL bindings for bulk upload, not just the change. The only trick here was to set the `toUpdate` property to `true` for all domains. I stripped out any `null` and `notConfigured` values to keep it tidier.

My next progression for this is to fetch my hostnames and certificate thumbprints and dynamically build the body before pushing the change to Azure.